# Problems with upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8, and I want to upgrade to Windows 8.1 so I can then upgrade to Windows 10.  I have so many problems, I don't know where to start.

I would think that I want to run an upgrade, but Microsoft seems to provide information only about an update.  The only info I can find is this page, *Install the Windows 8.1 Update (KB 2919355)*, at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15356/windows-8-install-update-kb-2919355, which says "If you’re running Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1 and you don’t have the update yet, ..." and that confuses me; how could I be running Windows 8.1 and not have the update yet?  Maybe they really are talking about an update that runs on Windows 8.1, that has nothing to do with the upgrade that I'm looking for.

Anyway, I run Windows Update, and it says "No updates are available".

I tried running *Store*, and it says "We weren't able to connect to the store. This might have happened because of a server problem or the network connection timed out.  Please wait a few minutes and try again".  I've waited a few minutes and tried again several times, and always get the same result.  My network connection is working fine (I used it to ask this question).

I'm running "Classic Start Menu", part of "Classic Shell", from http://www.classicshell.net/ , to avoid the touch-screen interface that came in with Windows 8 (I'm using a desktop computer).  It has always seemed to be well-behaved; I don't think it is interfering with running the *Store* app run from a charm (excuse my lack of fluency with these new terms.  I would gladly live without them).

As is so often the case, I find what looks like more useful info on a non-microsoft site.  http://www.extremetech.com/computing/178091-how-to-download-and-install-windows-8-1-update-1-for-free-right-now has links to KB2919442, KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2937592, KB2938439, and KB2934018.  It goes on to say "Once you’ve downloaded the initial Update 1, you will have six separate patches that need to be installed in a very specific order."  I have downloaded those six patches, but I don't know what "the initial Update 1" is that it mentions.  Maybe they're just sloppy with language, and the "initial Update 1" is the first of the six updates/patches.

My question is: how can I upgrade to Windows 8.1, either by solving any of these problems or by working around them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The articles you are mentioning are for updating `Windows 8.1` to `Windows 8.1 Update(1)`

They have nothing to do with Upgrading from `Windows 8` to `Windows 8.1`

If your Store application doesn't work, you can also [download the ISO for Windows 8.1 using the Microsoft Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/windows8) and install it.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much, but it certainly wasn't made clear.  Nor was it said anywhere that I could just upgrade to Windows 10 directly from Windows 8 -- I tried that and it worked.